# What's wrong with my code? My to do list don't work (pt-br)

Tags: javascript

My to-do list doesn't work the way I want it to. The error is in the part of clicking on finish a task, it finishes right but after that I can't finish any more. I don't know why this is. In addition, the "finish" starts with the last items, I need help with these two problems.

[One finished task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLFwr.png)
[Two finished tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwMv6.png)

```js
const tarefaInput = document.getElementById("tarefa");
const btnAdc = document.getElementById("adicionar");
const listaTarefas = document.getElementById("tarefas");
const listaFinalizadas = document.getElementById("finalizadas")

btnAdc.addEventListener("click", adicionarTarefa);

tarefaInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    adicionarTarefa();
  }
});

function adicionarTarefa() {
  const tarefaTexto = tarefaInput.value;
  if (tarefaTexto.trim() !== "") {
    const novaTarefa = document.createElement("li");
    novaTarefa.innerHTML = `
          ${tarefaTexto} <button class="excluir">Excluir</button> <button class="finalizar">Finalizar</button>
      `;
    listaTarefas.appendChild(novaTarefa);
    tarefaInput.value = "";

  }
  listaFinalizadas.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('finalizar')) {
      this.innerHTML = `${tarefaTexto} <button class="excluir">Excluir</button>` //não tá funcionando!!
      this.style.color = 'green'
    }
  })
}

listaTarefas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("excluir")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains("finalizar")) {
    listaFinalizadas.appendChild(e.target.parentElement)
  }
});

listaFinalizadas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("excluir")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<h1 id="titulo">MTE - Minhas Tarefas Escolares</h1>
<p id="detalhes"></p>

<div class="lista-tarefas">
  <input type="text" id="tarefa" placeholder="Adicione uma tarefa">
  <input type="button" value="Adicionar" id="adicionar">
  <h2>Tarefas Pendentes</h2>
  <ul id="tarefas">

  </ul>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h2>Tarefas Finalizadas</h2>
  <ul id="finalizadas">

  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to change the way I declared the variables, the functions, but none of it worked.

Comment: In what way(s)( did it not work as expected?

Comment: It is your mouseout code that causes it. Comment out that event listener and watch your code work. You are replacing the content... not sure what you are expecting that code to do.